# Python os.rename with datetime keeps saving multiple file same name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a timelapse running with `gphoto2` but it seems to be renaming all files to the same date and time

```
shot_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
shot_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")
```

```
def renameFiles(ID):
    for filename in os.listdir("."):
        if len(filename) < 14:
            if filename.endswith(".JPG"):
                os.rename (filename, (shot_time + ID + ".JPG"))
                print ("Renamed the jpeg boy")
            elif filename.endswith(".CR2"):
                os.rename (filename, (shot_time + ID + ".CR2"))
                print ("renamed cr2!")
```

Any ideas why it's taking the files and renaming them all to the same date & time as the script started? How can I call it to get the latest `datetime`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you created the `shot_time` before and you use it for all files. Try to generate the `shot_time` inside the loop.

For example:

```
def renameFiles(ID):
    for filename in os.listdir("."):
        if len(filename) < 14:
            shot_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")
            if filename.endswith(".JPG"):
                os.rename (filename, (shot_time + ID + ".JPG"))
                print ("Renamed the jpeg boy")
            elif filename.endswith(".CR2"):
                os.rename (filename, (shot_time + ID + ".CR2"))
                print ("renamed cr2!")
```